# Why can't an incomplete type be casted to void?

Tags: c++, void, incomplete-type

Why does the following code give the following error?

Why does the type need to be complete in order to be casted to `void`?

```
struct Incomplete;
class Class
{
    virtual void foo(Incomplete &incomplete)
    {
        (void) incomplete;
        throw std::logic_error("not implemented");
    }
};
```

Error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'Incomplete'  
    see declaration of 'Incomplete'
```

Comment: Why could it would be the more interesting question.  Simply use `(void)&incomplete` instead.

Comment: FWIW, GCC and clang don't have any problems with it.

Comment: It doesn't compile in VS2013, but compiles in [Microsoft's online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). So it's probably just a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: That makes me ask another question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/29181013/541686

Comment: @remyabel: Oh. Please post this as an answer!

Comment: Interesting. You don't even need a cast to `void`. Try `void foo(Incomplete &incomplete) { incomplete; }` and it will give you the exact same error.

Comment: Further indication that this seems to a buggy area of the compiler: try to declare an array of `Incomplete`, e.g. `Incomplete x[1];` It says `error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes`, which is a pretty strange message for what GCC calls `elements of array 'Incomplete x [1]' have incomplete type`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a change between C and C++, where Microsoft previously implemented the C rules. As noted in remyabel's answer, that has since been fixed.

In C, a cast to `void`, or simply using an expression as a statement by itself (as in `incomplete;`), still involves the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. C calls it slightly differently, but it's the same conversion.

In C++, a cast to `void`, or simply using an expression as a statement by itself doesn't involve the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This is needed because C++ makes assignment operators return lvalues, so if the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion were applied, then

```
volatile int i;
i = 1;
```

would not merely store, it would also immediately load afterwards.

The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion requires a complete type, even if the value is then discarded, since otherwise, it's impossible to know how many bytes should be read.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything prohibiting this, quoting N4140:

> §5.4/4 The conversions performed by
>
> [...]
>
> — a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
>
> [...]
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.
>
> §5.2.9/5 Otherwise, the `static_cast` shall perform one of the
>   conversions listed below. No other conversion shall be performed
>   explicitly using a `static_cast`.
>
> §5.2.9/6 Any expression can be explicitly converted to type cv void,
>   in which case it becomes a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).
>   [...]

It's most likely a bug as tested on [Rextester](http://rextester.com/runcode), an online VS2013 compiler, but compiles in [rise4fun](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/), Microsoft's online compiler which is bleeding edge.