# Is it legal to cast a forward-declared type to void?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, doxygen, forward-declaration

Below is a C++ header file that compiles without error under g++ and clang, but under MSVC2015, it errors out on the `(void) copyFrom` line, with the error `C2027: use of undefined type 'blah::SomeOtherClass'`.

My question is:  is this code legal according to the C++ standard?  Or if the code is not correct (i.e. because casting a parameter to (void) legitimately requires more than just a forward-declaration), then what would be a good way to retain my DOxygen documentation for the `copyFrom` argument without introducing unwanted `parameter copyFrom was never referenced` warnings into my compiler-output?  (Note that the full definition of `SomeOtherClass` isn't available at this point, since `SomeOtherClass` depends on `DummyImplementation`)

```
#ifndef blah_h
#define blah_h

namespace blah {

class SomeOtherClass;

/** Example of the problem at hand */
class DummyImplementation
{
public:
   /** Dummy implemention of CopyFrom().
    *  @param copyFrom This parameter is ignored.
    *  @returns zero.
    */
   int CopyFrom(const SomeOtherClass & copyFrom)
   {
      (void) copyFrom;  // error C2027: use of undefined type 'blah::SomeOtherClass'
      return 0;
   }
};

} // end namespace blah

#endif
```

Update:  Per Francois' request, here are the build my program uses when building with `MSVC 19.0.24210.0` (not that the answer to a question about the requirements of the C++ standard should depend on the behavior of a particular version of MSVC):

```
cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline /nologo /MP 
/arch:SSE2 /Zi -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 
-EHsc -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DNDEBUG -D__WIN32__ -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES 
-DQT_NO_CAST_ASCII -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
[... various -I flags omitted ...]
```

Comment: This produces no assembly with gcc 7 or cland 6 and produces no error message. It also compiles fine with Visual Studio 2015. Please read about [MCVE]s and specify which compiler, which compiler version and which compiler flags produce the results you observe.

Comment: In this case I believe it should be ok because: `Any expression can be explicitly converted to type “cv void.” The expression value is discarded.`... so in theory you are not really using/referencing the variable copyFrom.   But, strictly speaking it should not be allowed to reference a forward declared type variable in your implementation... I guess this particular case is up to the compiler!? - does it "void" the expression first or does it check the usage of the incomplete type first?

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether that triggers an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, which requires a complete type.  Rather a pain when you want to force a read from a volatile variable and discard the result, on some compilers `(void)vvar;` is enough, on others you have to write `(void)+vvar;`

Comment: Which version of ```doxygen``` are you referring to? Do you want to write ```int CopyFrom(const SomeOtherClass & )```? otherwise also state the ```doxygen``` problem a bit clearer.

Comment: You may want to try `std::addressof(copyFrom)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the full story, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181143/1348273) answer.

According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast), for `(type-name) expression` (emphasis mine)

> If `type-name` is `void`, then `expression` is evaluated for its side-effects and its returned value is discarded, **same as when `expression` is used on its own**, as an expression statement.

That is, `(void)copyFrom` is equivalent to `copyFrom` which has no effect, and should not require a complete type in C++.

By the way, your code compiles fine with MSVC 2017 ([live](https://godbolt.org/g/2gFwZg)).

To suppress the compiler warning, you may consider:

```
std::addressof(copyFrom)
```